# Javascript Promise return value can be logged but not used

Tags: javascript, php, promise, axios

I'm still fairly new to Promises, and thought I had a grip on them, but this issue has me stuck. My code:

```
return axios.post('./getParks.php')
.then((daysGames)=> {
  console.log(daysGames.data);
  let dailyData = daysGames.data;
  Object.keys(dailyData).map((day)=> {
```

Upon running the console logs this:

```
Object {1: Object, 2: Object..}
TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined
```

I have also tried the following resulting in the same error:

```
let dailyParks = axios.post('./getParks.php');
return dailyParks
.then((daysGames)=> {
  console.log(daysGames.data);
  let dailyData = daysGames.data;
  Object.keys(dailyData).map((day)=> {
```

Comment: Did you try JSON.parse(daysGames) before reaching daysGames.data ?

Comment: @muratgozel The value returned by getParks.php is already an object

Comment: if you change this line `console.log(daysGames.data);` to this `console.log(Object.keys(daysGames));` can you see correctly the `data` property in the console?

Comment: you probably have problems with `getParks`  return value. You used `return` but not `echo`, right?

Comment: @marmeladze I used `echo` and it's all functioning correctly again with the change I put in my answer below. Is using `echo` bad practice?

Answer (score 0):

Well I've fixed it, but I'm not totally sure why it worked. If someone could enlighten me to the reasoning it would be much appreciated

```
return axios.post('./getParks.php')
.then((daysGames)=> {
  console.log(daysGames.data);
  let dailyData = daysGames;
  Object.keys(dailyData.data).map((day)=> {
```

Comment: the code in this answer is functionally identical as the first code in the question - so, you must have "fixed" something else as well

Comment: You really aren't showing us enough code and you aren't being explicit enough about the problem is or what you changed for us to even participate in this question.